# How to mock private class using jmockit?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jmockit

```
public String processName() throws Exception {

    String name = dbManager.getName(); // getname
    String connection = dbManager.getConnection();
    String name2 = dbManager.getName();
    Mydata mydata = new Mydata();
    String getData = mydata.getGetData();
    List<String> list = dbManager.getList();
    return getData.toLowerCase();
}

private class Mydata {
    String getData = "test";

    public String getGetData() {
        return getData;
    }
    public void setGetData(String getData) {
        this.getData = getData;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not expected to test a `private` method. You should write the test for `public` methods and put a `verify` on the mocks if they are being called in any of your `private` methods.

Comment: my question is i want to mock the public method of the private class is it possible??

Comment: Yes, you might be able to mock it but in general since `private` classes are like black-boxes you should avoid writing them.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not be using `private` classes and avoid writing the tests for them as they are supposed to be `black-boxes` for the outer world.

But still if you are using one and want to mock it then here is how you can do it using JMockit:

```
Object ins = Deencapsulation.newInnerInstance("Mydata", outerClass.class, (Object[]) null);
```

I have used `null` because you have not defined any constructor on your inner private class.

Here is the documentation if you are interested:

> Object mockit.Deencapsulation.newInnerInstance(String
> innerClassSimpleName, Object outerClassInstance, Object...
> nonNullArgs)
>
> The same as newInstance(String, Class[], Object), but for
> instantiating an inner non-accessible class of some other class, and
> where all other (if any) initialization arguments are known to be
> non-null.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *innerClassSimpleName:*
> the inner class simple name, that is, the part after the "$" character in its full name
>
> *outerClassInstance:*
> the outer class instance to which the inner class instance will belong
>
> *nonNullArgs:*
> zero or more non-null parameter values for the invocation; if a null value needs to be passed, the Class object for the
> corresponding parameter type must be passed instead  type to which
> the returned instance should be assignable
>
> **Returns:** a newly created instance of the specified inner class, initialized > with the given arguments
>
> **Throws:** IllegalArgumentException - if a null reference was provided for a parameter

Comment: but How can i mock this method String getData = mydata.getGetData();i tried but it does not mock this line Mydata mydata = new Mydata();